# EditText being overlapped by the soft keyboard

Tags: android

Why is that when I press done on the keyboard or press the back button, the EditText isn't animated again to the top of the keyboard. So the 2nd time the keyboard appears the layout doesn't get resized.

Here's my xml:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/share_caption"
android:maxLines="1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
android:textColor="#ff696969"/>
```

Apparently setting the gravity is the cause. But this is essential if you want to center the text or the hint.

-EDIT-

After reading the docs about `windowSoftInputMode` and `adjustPan` seems to be fit for the job but It doesn't work with the android:gravity="center"

Comment: Place your layout in Scroll view and use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for that activity in Manifest

Comment: Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` for your particular activity in your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

add following line to activity tag in android manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

The one you added is for handling of config changes yourself.

Example:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

define the following attribute in `<activity>` of AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following attribute in `activity` of `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
            android:name="com.domain.app.MyActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```